# Function triggered when not called in Svelte component

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm giving a try to Svelte by building a simple to-do app. Here's the whole component:

```
<script>
    let newTask = '';
    let showCompleted = true;

    let tasks = [{
        name: 'Test task',
        completed: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Test task 2',
        completed: true
    }];

    $: filterTasks = tasks.filter(task => showCompleted === true ? true : task.completed === false);

    function addTask() {
        tasks = [...tasks, {
            name: newTask,
            completed: false
        }];
        newTask = '';
    };

    function updateTask(updatedTask) {
        tasks = tasks.map(task => {
            if(task === updatedTask) {
                return {...updatedTask, completed: !task.completed};
            } else {
                return task;
            }
        });
    };
</script>

<h1>To-do</h1>

<label><input type="checkbox" bind:checked={showCompleted}> Show completed</label>

<ul>
    {#each filterTasks as task}
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={task.completed} on:change={updateTask(task)}>
            {task.name}
        </li>
    {/each}
</ul>

<input type="text" bind:value="{newTask}">
<button on:click|preventDefault={addTask}>Add</button>
```

But I'm running into multiple issues:

- `updateTask` is triggered for every tasks at page loading and the never work anymore when the checkbox are clicked
- The filtering of the complete task just does not work
- When I add a task, it directly complete the last one

I have the feeling I might have missed something at some point and it's causing all those issues but, can't manage to found what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the thing you missed is that you need to pass a callback function to `on:change` event handler, i.e. `on:change={() => updateTask(task)}`. Right now it just calls `updateTask` immediately.
Here is the [updated REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/faf044751c6d4086ae685a07216897e3?version=3.5.3), I could not reproduce the other issues you mentioned